# Pb under JQuery and PHP : passing arg with GET to show content detail

Tags: php, jquery

I want to see a list of content in a sidebar.
When i click on a particular content in this sidebar that should refresh the content detail  with its info.

2 pages : test_content.php and test_content_detail.php.

```
<?php
/*
  $Id:  test_content.php $
  Show all content
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="./js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadContent(id) {
            var $element = $('#content');
            var $response = $element.load("test_content_detail.php?id="+id+" #content_detail");
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="items">
            <div id="1" class="item">  
                    <input type="button" value="Should show 1" onClick="loadContent(1);">
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="item">  
                    <input type="button" value="Should show 2" onClick="loadContent(2);">
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="item">  
                    <input type="button" value="Should show 3" onClick="loadContent(3);">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content_detail">
            empty
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Call by jquery :

```
<?php
/*
  $Id:  Test_content_detail.php $
  Show one content
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="./js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fillDetail(){
             var html = '<br>My detail : ';
             var id = "<?php print $_GET['id']?>"; // Where the PHP do the job
             if (id){
                     html += "my id = "+id;
              }
              var $detail = $('#content_detail');
              $detail.append(html);
        };

        $(document).ready(fillDetail);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar">
        none
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content_detail">
            supposed to be filled with <?php print $_GET['id']?>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Test_content_detail.php?id=3*** is correct.
But what i see when i click on 3 is "**supposed to be filled with 3**" without the detail.

A sequence pb ?
Thx in advance !

Comment: is it `test_content_detail.php` or `Test_content_detail.php`? What is Pb?

Comment: The pb is when i launch _test_content.php_ and when i click on "Click 3" for example. I'm waiting for "My detail : my id = 3". But i don't know why _fillDetail()_ function doesn't do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

Response from friend : "**No Javascript in AJAX call**".

*$(document).ready(fillDetail)* can't be launch by the $element.load("test_content_detail.php")

Solution : include all the js in the same content file.